# How to fix errorcode CS1503?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, error-handling, httpresponse

```
public async void GetWeatherInfo(CityName city)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(city);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={0}&appid=29d06aa8c8b3a8341ab876b124d7c&units=metric",json));

        var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            try
            {
                var weatherInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherInfo>(**result**);
        }}}
```

I am working on a weather app project and I am trying to get a string city name from the user. I binded the city name to url and wrote GetRequest but I am getting an error with "**result**" at the end of the code. It should deserialize the response so i can alter the response and use it.  The error message is:**cannot convert from 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'string'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

The `HttpClient.getAsync()` method, returns an `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` which also includes the status code and more information about the response itself.

> Returns Task{HttpResponseMessage}
>
> The task object representing the asynchronous operation.`

[Check documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=netframework-4.8)

You need to extract the content from the result.

## Solution

Try this

```
public async void GetWeatherInfo(CityName city)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(city);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={0}&appid=29d06aa8c8b3a8341ab876b124d7c&units=metric",json));

        var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            try
            {
                string content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var weatherInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherInfo>(content);
        }}}
```

Comment: Worth nothing you should avoid `async void` in your method declaration. Instead use `async Task`.